# Increasing swapfile size for Windows container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm getting following error when I launch docker interactive mode.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)
```

This container is running on Windows 10 host machine and I allocated 5GB RAM. I'm running this container in dev environment and I have no other container running. My question, how do I increase swap file size for container? Is that something that needs to be done in dockerfile?

Docker : 19.03.2